# Route connections via an IPv6 IP address?

Tags: iptables, nat, ipv6

I have a dedicated server with a big block of IPv6 IPs.

I'd like to be able to use a randomized IPv6 IP within that block and run all outgoing connections through that single selected IP.

I've already accomplished the same thing with IPv4 by using iptables:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -m tcp ! -s XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX -j SNAT --to-source XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
```

Since ip6tables doesn't seem to have a NAT table, I started looking for alternatives...
One alternative I found is :  [NATP66](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nat66stateful/) .

If I installed and compiled everything for NATP66 to work I think I could probably use this ip6tables rule:

```
ip6tables -t nat66 -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -m tcp ! -s IPV6_IP_GOES_HERE -j SNAT66 --to-range IPV6_IP_GOES_HERE
```

The thing I didn't like about NATP66 is the fact that I have to recompile the kernel in order to make it work (and I really want to stay away from having to do that unless it was my last option).

Comment: May one ask WHY you're trying to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to just add the addresses you want to use to a real or dummy interface and then just configure your application to use them.